# jquery-ui: resizable not resizing with custom handler

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I want to resize an element using [`jquery-ui`](https://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/). Although this is easily done, however I want a draggable handler in the middle (checkout [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qzTJ/767/))

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="resizable resizable1"> ... </div>
    <div class="resizable resizable2"> ... </div>
    <div id="p" class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.resizable1').resizable({
    handles: {
        'e': '#p'
    },
    ....
```

The problem is that it is not possible to resize the `resizable`s using the custom handler now. Is there a solution to fix this ? Or should I abandon jquery-ui and find something else

Comment: use css and change the resizable icon when on the edge of the resizables (right of resizable1 or left of resizable2) then when a resizable is resized left or right (if i understab\nd this correctly) resize the other reesizable also in the reverse direction so the analogy is maintained